# подключение к удаленному компьютеру потеряно возможно из за неполадок

Tags: linux, windows, rdp

У меня есть VPS с ubuntu 18.4, я хочу подключится к ней через графический пользовательский интерфейс с windows 10 (мой комп)

На сервере я установил графический интерфейс по этой коротокой инструкции: https://blog.vpsville.ru/blog/howto/176.html.

Подключаюсь к серверу через стандартную утилиту windows.

Он подключается, открывается интерфейс ubuntu 18.4, потом я ввожу пароль администратора и внезапно соединение обравается.

Винда пишет предупреждение подключение к удаленному компьютеру потеряно возможно из за неполадок и т.д.
 Мои действия:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почитайте хоть логи на сервере для приличия что ли

Comment: [какой-то очередной баг убунты](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12073) p.s. прежде чем вводить какие-либо пароли, бывает полезно прочитать, что же от вас требуется, и **иногда** нажать «cancel» вместо «ok».